# Performance measures : Java vs JavaCard

Tags: java, performance, time, smartcard, javacard

I implemented two algorithms in Java.

To compare their effectiveness, I call each function 1000 times and compare the execution time (using `System.currentTimeMillis()`).

It needs 2500 ms to execute the first one and 1300 ms for the second one.

With these results, I thought have a significative difference (in term of execution time) in JavaCard.

But if I load 2 applets on a JavaCard, which correspond to the functions described, the first one takes 2000 ms and the second one 1750 ms...

**How explain that in Java, it looks almost 2 times faster, but not in JavaCard ?**
I paid attention that I don't write in EEPROM but in RAM so it can't be the source of the problem.

Do you have any argument to explain this phenomenon ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Mandatory comment "How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: Java and JavaCard are two completely different technologies - they share only a subset of syntax,  that is all. Just the word "JavaCard" can be a little misleading... I think you should not look for any connection between Java and JavaCard.

Comment: Show me the algorithm code please。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run the algorithm is in two different platform, so the final machine language is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Benchmark testing is not straightforward in Java. You can't just call a method in a loop and expect consistent and reliable results. You have to take into account many factors, compiler optimization and GC just to name a few. Pick up a performance testing tool for Java to do it properly.